# Question edit form

Tags: bug, edits

I am not sure if it is a bug but when I try to edit a question and someone else is editing the page, I get redirected to the page below. I could understand the error message but just thought it would be nice to let the developer know.

[image: edit form error]

This doesn't happen always, I only experienced it once. It happened on mac using chrome(Version 60.0.3112.90).

Comment: @NathanOliver : of course I could understand that but it seems weird as the UI was changed.

Comment: you have to change the question

Comment: Are you actually clicking on a link and getting this or are you directly navigating to it?  From the front end you shouldn't even be able to click edit if there is a pending one.

Comment: @NathanOliver i clicked from the front-end. There is no point in directly navigating to it.

Comment: Hun.  I did an experiment and [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hj53N.png) should be what you get when you click on edit.  Maybe this is a bug

Comment: @NathanOliver Exactly that's what I get everytime but one particular time, I got the below output. I also pointed out in my question `I am not sure if it is a bug`.

Comment: It usually helps to include browser and OS information in bug reports.  Chrome on Mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when an edit suggestion is submitted *between* the time you click the edit button and the moment the edit page itself is loaded. It *would* be nice if you would be redirected back to the question/answer you were viewing, but these cases should be fairly rare.

A similar thing happens when you visit the edit page of a Meta post on a Meta where you don't have enough reputation to edit posts, e.g. this link:

https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/490/edit

The interesting thing is that the error message in this case is the same as yours, and flat out wrong:

> There is a pending suggested edit in the queue. Try again in a few minutes.

[image]

Instead, it should show something that suggested edits aren't allowed on Meta.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. It would be really helpful if they provided a different message and also in this case, a redirection is not necessary.